# Refund a Zero Subtotal Checkout order

Tags: payment-methods, refund, ce-1.9.1.0

We have some coupons that make an order's value be zero. Thus they checkout with the Zero Subtotal Payment method. We can make the Zero Subtotal Payment method make orders Pending or Processing with automatic invoicing. Problem comes when we want to cancel the order after the order has been invoiced.

Normally we can just refund the credit card and cancel the order. But Zero Subtotal has no refund method and disables the cancel button.

Is this a bug or is there really no way to not ship an order thats been marked processing by the Zero Subtotal Payment method.

This is extremely problematic when we edit an order, which creates a new ###-1 order and gives us no way to cancel the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View on line 92 you have a check $order->canCreditmemo() the on line 649 of Mage_Sales_Model_Order you have:

`if (abs($this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getTotalPaid()) - $this->getTotalRefunded()) < .0001) {
            return false;
        }`

This returns false in your case. I think the only way would be to override this model, and then the Credit Memo button would appear.